# Why the webpage sometimes has .extension sometimes doesn't?

Tags: php, html, asp.net

I am new in the web development. My question is Why the webpage sometimes has .extension sometimes doesn't?

For example:
This site has the webpage name featurelist.aspx:
- http://www.nopcommerce.com/featurelist.aspx 
and 
this page does not contain the extension:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?

Comment: Search for "URL rewriting".

Answer (score 0):

It can be done many ways.

1) writing rule to shorten the url and hide extension

2) showing the path of a folder that contains index file. If a path to folder is given and that contains a index file then that index page doesn't need to be shown in url

3)Frameworks use routing to interprete URL which sometimes doesn't show extensions

AND MANY MORE. Simply these are some reasons